# Make rowspan be 2 if index of v-for is different than 2 values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the following table:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-sm table-striped table-bordered" id="list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th v-for="(column, index) in columns" :key="index" :rowspan="{ '2': index != 'new_value' || 'old_value' }">
                {{ column }}
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(entry, index) in results" :key="index">
            <td v-for="(key, index) in columns" :key="index">
                {{ entry._source[index] }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In which I want the rowspan for the table head that isn't `new_value` or `old_value` to be 2, however in the current code the table head has a `[object Object]` instead of a number:

```
<th rowspan="[object Object]">User</th>
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is `"new_value" || "old_value"` ?

Comment: @Psidom Its two of the indexes inside the `columns` array that is run by the v-for, being it "id", "user", "type", "old_value", "new_value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rowspan` attribute expects a number not an object. Try:

```
:rowspan="index !== 'new_value' && index !== 'old_value' ? 2 : 1"
```

Comment: That applied 2 to all THs.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `&&`. Confused by your original syntax.